# BindElement() on form in popup dialog / fragment

Tags: sapui5

Following on from my question about [Is it possible to use 2 models in one view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753783/is-it-possible-to-use-2-models-in-one-view) I am now confused about how to apply bindElement on a form in an XML fragment.

The fragment (cut down for brevity):

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
   namespaces here...>
    <Dialog id="theDialogId" title="Edit Subdetail">
        <content>
            <f:SimpleForm id="EditFormId" editable="true" >
                <f:content>
                    <Label id="lblName" text="Name" labelFor="inpName" />
                    <Input id="inpName" editable="true" value="{name}"/>
                </f:content>
            </f:SimpleForm>
        </content>
    </Dialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

The challenge: Assume I have a model containing path `/master/0/detail/6/subdetail/2` - how to bind the simpleform to this path? Im the examples I have seen, elements in dialogs are given a value by

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("inputId").setValue("some value)
```

and accessed via

```
var uid = sap.ui.getCore().byId("inputId").getValue()
```

However I want to employ binding to the path.

The issue I have is how to get a reference to the simpleform so that I can use bindElement().

If this were a view I would use

```
var theForm = this.getView().byId("EditFormId");

var oBindingContext = event.oSource.getBindingContext();
theForm.bindElement(oBindingContext.getPath())
```

However fragments are not tightly coupled to the view so this will not work. Instead I believe I have to use

```
var dlgForm = sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId("theFragmentId", "EditFormId")

var oBindingContext = event.oSource.getBindingContext();
dlgForm.bindElement(oBindingContext.getPath())
```

This may well be correct but I am at a loss as to how to apply the "theFragmentId" in the XML view declaration. Can anyone clear the fog for me?

EDIT: What I was missing, as per the accepted answer, is that the desired fragment ID can be given as the first (optional) parameter of the sap.ui.xmlfragment() function. The key to binding into a fragment-based control is to get a handle to it but the  sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId(fragId, ctrlId) function requires a fragment id. My issue was that I was fixated on the XML fragment declaration and how to apply an id there. This feels inconsistent within SAPUI5 but I guess being able to apply an ID to the fragment has some amenity somewhere, maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this...

```js
onOpenDialog: function(oEvent) {
    if(!this._oEditSubDetailDialog){
            this._oEditSubDetailDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("fragmentId", "namespace.and.path.to.your.fragment", this);
            this.getView().addDependent(this._oEditSubDetailDialog);
    }

    var sPathToBind = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getPath();
    sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId("fragmentId","EditFormId").bindElement(sPathToBind);

    this._oEditSubDetailDialog.open();
}
```

...just need to make sure that the source control of the event has the context bound to it that you want to edit.

You could also bindElement directly on the dialog, this way you would not need to retrieve the form control within the dialog...

```
this._oEditSubDetailDialog.bindElement(sPathToBind)
```

[This API documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html#.xmlfragment) and [this walkthrough guide](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/4da72985139b4b83b5f1c1e0c0d2ed5a.html) regarding XML fragments may be useful

Comment: Thanks Ian. Your example code and  link to the API docs illuminated the point that the desired fragment ID can be given as the first (optional) parameter of the sap.ui.xmlfragment() function - something that I had not seen in all the examples I had seen, including Section 16 of the walkthrough which is a simple confirm / reset dialogue example.

Comment: sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId("fragmentId","EditFormId").bindElement(sPathToBind); why this sPathToBind?

I have two models oModel1 is for table binding in view. oModel2 is for fragment binding. this.getView().setModel(oModel1, "table"); this.getView().setModel(oModel2, "list"); is this possible?

Comment: Solved my problem by `this._oEditSubDetailDialog.setModel(this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("myModel"))` & `this._oEditSubDetailDialog.bindElement(sPathToBind)`